# Vim autocompletion from library included in another file

Tags: c, file, vim, autocomplete

I use Fedora 24. I write Ansi C programs in Vim, using it's native autocompletion under ^N. And everything works fine until I define library in another file like this:

fileA.c

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include "fileB.c"
```

fileB.c

```
...
```

If I try to autocomplete in fileA.c it looks up in both file b and library.
But in file a it searches only in fileA.c. How can I look up for library's functions and constants in fileB.c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in `fileA.c`, completions are pulled (among other places) from all includes in that file and includes in those includes, recursively.

This happens because the default value of `'complete'` contains `i`.

When you are in `fileB.c`, completions can't be pulled from any include because you don't seem to have any but they can still be pulled from the current buffer (`.` in `complete`), other buffers (`w`, `b`, `u`), and even `tags` files (`t`).

That said, explicitly including a resource is necessary in C if you want to use it so I'm not sure it is wise to expect *any* resource to be available in your code without proper includes.